# How "should" or "do" you respond

Tags: modal-verbs

> "How **should** you respond to 
>   congratulations?"

OR

> "How **do** you respond to congratulations?"

Do these two sentences convey the same idea?

Answer (score 3):

No. They do not have the same meaning.

"How should you respond..." solicits an advice regarding the 'proper' way of responding to a 'congratulations'.

"How do you respond..." solicits the idea about a person's own way of responding to a 'congratulations'.